# Unable to register Docker service with Registrator

Tags: docker, devops, consul

I have a docker, docker-compose and Consul installed on my local machine. Now I want to register one of my services in Consul using Registrator. The Dockerfile of my service is as simple as:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY code/ /var/www/html/
ENV SERVICE_ID=php
ENV SERVICE_NAME=php-apache
```

Besides, I have Consul running. I can check it with simple commands like:

```
$ curl -X PUT 'Hello world ' 127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/msg1
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/msg1?raw
Hello world
```

I then start registartor container, following one of the tutorials:

```
$ sudo docker run -d --name registrator-consul -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
-h jacobian-VirtualBox gliderlabs/registrator \
-ip 127.0.0.1 consul://127.0.0.1:8500
```

Wnen I run the above command, I get some big key in the console:

```
a25a48 ... 3b69
```

Everything looks good, since I get no error messages. If however I check

```
$ docker ps
```

I see no active images

But at the same time, if I run

```
$ docker ps -a
```

I see this row at the very top:

```
CONTAINER ID    ...    STATUS

##somecode##    ...    Exited(1) 52 seconds ago
```

This is exactly registrator-consul container and what I do not like is that it exited. I did not do it myself, so it is really strange that it is not in active state.

I finally build and run my php-apache container:

```
$ docker build -t php-apache.
$ docker run -d --name php-apache -p 8181:80 php-apache
```

At this moment, everything works great. I can even check that my service is working. So, when I go to localhost:8181, I see a nice page rendered with Apache web server. BUT. My task is to check whether it was registered in Consul or not. I check it like so:

```
$ curl jacobian-VirtualBox:8500/v1/catalog/services | jq '.'
```

But as a result of this command I see this in the console:

```
{
    "consul": []
}
```

So, no services were registered. My question is why? What I did wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: To those kind people who down vote. Please, share your thoughts on the topic.

Comment: I misunderstood some things. At first how can you do `curl` request to jacobian container if it exited? At second as I saw consul registrator and your apache server don't communicate each other. Why consul should register your apache server?

Comment: The whole problem was in how registrator container is run. I removed `-ip 127.0.0.1`  and added `--net=host` and it started to work.

Comment: @ Cortwave. As for your first question, the simple answer is - I do not know. It just works as it works. As for youe second question, I do not know what make you believe that registrator and apache server need to communicate with each other. As far as I know, registrator just listens to all docker events through the socket (or somehow) and makes registration. So, I don't think that there should be some explicit communication between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run your registrator with `-h` param. `-h` - just hostname for your container, not host where it will be deployed. Also you pass `127.0.0.1` as your Consul server address to registrator. `127.0.0.1` is loopback interface for registrator container - not for your host with running Consul server. If your Consul server running on your host (if you can access it by `127.0.0.1:8500`) then you need to add `--net=host` param to your registrator run.

P.S. I don't know real address of `jacobian-VirtualBox` host that you are using in `curl` request. In the case if it's not `127.0.0.1` it will not work and your need to connect your registrator container with Consul service other way (connect to other net or specify other Consul server address if it's available inside registrator container.

Comment: Thanks! But could you please advise how to set this `--net=host` param through `docker-compose.yml`? I asked a question devoted purely to this parameter at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681944/unable-to-run-registrator-using-docker-compose-get-connection-refused-error . So, I warmly welcome you and hope you can share one more advise. Thanks!