# Unable to run Registrator using docker-compose. Get connection refused error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have Consul and a bunch of services on my local machine. Now I want to implement service registration in Consul using Registrator. If I do it like so:

```
$ docker run -d --name registrator --net=host \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock gliderlabs/registrator \
  consul://127.0.0.1:8500
```

And after that run some services, I see that they are registered in Consul. If however I try to do it via docker-compose.yml (since I do not want to run the above command each time by hand):

```
version: '2'
services:
    consul:
        image: gliderlabs/consul-server:latest
        command: "advertise=127.0.0.1 -server -bootstrap"
        container_name: consul
        hostname: 127.0.0.1
        ports:
            - "8500:8500"
    registrator:
        image: gliderlabs/registrator:latest
        command: "consulL//127.0.0.1:8500"
        container_name: registrator
        hostname: 127.0.0.1
        depends_on: 
            - consul
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock

   ... other services that need to be registered
```

And run:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

then I see in the console this error message:

```
registrator | 2017/01/16 17:01:24 Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/status/leader dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: connection refused
```

I guess, my problem is related to the fact, that I didn't specify `--net=host`. But I do not know how can I do that. I hope, someone knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker-compose creates new network for all your services in `docker-compose.yml` by default. If you need to attach your container to host network add to your service network mode param:

```
...
registrator:
  network_mode: host
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will check it in a second.

Comment: Hello, Cortwave! I posted another question, devoted to Consul and Registrator - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697466/not-all-services-are-registered-in-consul-with-registrator . Shortly, one of my services is not registered in Consul and I do not know why. Probably, you have some thoughts and can spend a minute or so to share your advise, Thanks again!