# Not all services are registered in Consul with Registrator

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I have Docker and Docker Compose on my machine and I have a docker-compose.yml file. Inside of this file I define two services like so

```
 ...
 nginx:
     build:
         context: ./nginx-proxy' 
     image: nginx-proxy
     container_name: nginx
     ports:
         - 8181:80
     links:
         - consul-server
         - php
     depends_on:
         -registrator

php:
    build:
        context: ./php-apache
    image: php-apache
    container_name: php-apache
    depends_on:
        - registrator

...
```

It is quite a big docker-compose.yml file, which also contains definitions of consul-server and registrator containers. At first glance, everything works good. When I run:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

I see that all my containers are running and I see no error messages. I can even check, that for example php container is indeed running (just going to localhost:8181, I see a nice html page rendered with this service). However, the problem is, this php service is not registered with Registrator. I check it like so:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8500/v1/catalog/services
```

As a result, I get this:

```
{"consul-server-8500":[], "nginx-proxy-80":[]}
```

So, for some strange reason Registrator registered successfully nginx-proxy service, but skipped php service. I wonder why. I really need it, since based on this, I would create consul templates for nginx-proxy service. So, I need some help.

**EDIT**

This is how I define consul and registrator services:

```
version: '2'
services:
    consul-server:
        build:
            context: ./consul-server
        hostname: ${MYHOST}
        ports:
            - 8500:8500
    registrator:
        build:
            context: ./registrator
        container_name: registrator
        command: "consul://${MYHOST}:8500"
        hostname: ${MYHOST}
        network_mode: host
        depends_on:
            - consul-server
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
```

And this is how my registrator Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM gliderlabs/registrator:latest
ENV SERVICE_ID=registrator
ENV SERVICE_NAME=registrator
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/registrator"]
```

**Registrator log**

Not sure, if it is important:

```
2017/01/17 11:52:52 Starting registrator v7 ...
2017/01/17 11:52:52 Using consul adapter: consul://127.0.0.1:8500
2017/01/17 11:52:52 Connecting to backend (0/0)
2017/01/17 11:52:52 consul: current leader
2017/01/17 11:52:52 Listening for Docker events ...
2017/01/17 11:52:52 Syncing services on 2 containers
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: c7251ebcbec4 no published ports
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: d22263dca979 port 8301 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: d22263dca979 port 8302 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: d22263dca979 port 8600 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: d22263dca979 port 8600 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: d22263dca979 port 8300 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: d22263dca979 port 8302 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: d22263dca979 port 8301 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:52 added: d22263dca979 consul
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: d22263dca979 port 8400 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: c7251ebcbec4 no published ports
2017/01/17 11:52:52 ignored: 74a190734619 port 80 not published on host
2017/01/17 11:52:53 added: bd9f65b332a5 nginx
2017/01/17 11:52:53 ignored: bd9f65b332a5 port 443 not published on host
```

As far as I can see Registrator ignores my php service (docker id=74a190734619). But I do not know how can I fix it.

Comment: Is it a bug - https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator/issues/474 ?

Comment: which docker-compose version are you using? Since docker-compose v2 links are deprecated and networks should be used instead. Also add registrator service declaration.

Comment: How can I check docker-compose version? As for registrator service declaration, I will post in several minutes.

Comment: if your `docker-compose.yml` has `version '2'` declaration at the top - then it v.2, if it ommitted then it v. 1. It's preferable to use v.2

Comment: Just a second. I will now add some extra information to my question.

Comment: Made an update. Please, have a look.

Comment: attach your registrator cantainer log please

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how can I do that here at SO. Besides, I'm new to Docker terminology and I'm not sure what exactly you mean by container here.

Comment: BTW, I posted Dockerfile for my registrator container. And can do the same for consul-server, nginx and php, if it may help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133370/discussion-between-cortwave-and-jacobian).

Comment: Made a new comment in chat room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to logs registrator registers only those ports which published to your host. And it make sense. Consul is service discovery tool and there is no sense to register services which has no published ports.

P.S. you can remove links from your docker-compose as you are using version 2 (links are deprecated and networks usage more preferable). It's not about your problem. Just advice.

Comment: So, if I remove links, I could still refer from one container to another by service name?

Comment: yes, they are in common docker network by default and can resolve each other by service name

Comment: And I will check it in a second, what will happen, if I publish ports for php service. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Sorry for bothering you :( I hope, you will have a free minute to have look at another my question (I guess it would be the last one, since now it is devoted to the final task that I want to achive). The question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712994/unable-to-load-balance-using-docker-consul-and-nginx . Thanks in advance!