# Unable to load balance using Docker, Consul and nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, load-balancing, docker-compose, consul-template

What I want to achive is load balancing using this stack: Docker, Docker Compose, Registrator, Consul, Consul Template, NGINX and, finally, a tiny service that prints out "Hello world" in browser. So, at this moment I have a docker-compose.yml file. It looks like so:

```
version: '2'
services:
accent:
    build:
        context: ./accent
    image: accent
    container_name: accent
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 80
consul:
    image: gliderlabs/consul-server:latest
    container_name: consul
    hostname: ${MYHOST}
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 8300:8300
        - 8400:8400
        - 8500:8500
        - 8600:53/udp
    command: -advertise ${MYHOST} -data-dir /tmp/consul -bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0
registrator:
    image: gliderlabs/registrator:latest
    container_name: registrator
    hostname: ${MYHOST}
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    command: -ip ${MYHOST} consul://${MYHOST}:8500
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - /etc/nginx
    ports:
        - 8181:80
consul-template:
    container_name: consul-template
    build:
        context: ./consul-template
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    volumes_from:
        - nginx
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    command: -consul=${MYHOST}:8500 -wait=5s -template="/etc/ctmpl/nginx.ctmpl:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:docker kill -s HUP nginx"
```

The first service - accent - is that my web service that I need to load balance. When I run this command:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

I see that all services start to run and I see no error messages. It looks as if everything is just perfect. When I run

```
$ docker ps
```

I see this in the console:

```
... NAMES              STATUS            PORTS
consul-template    Up 45 seconds     
consul             Up 56 seconds     0.0.0.0:8300->8300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8400->8400/tcp, 8301-8302/tcp, 8301-8302/udp, 0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp, 8600/tcp, 8600/udp, 0.0.0.0:8600->53/udp    
nginx              Up 41 seconds     0.0.0.0:8181->80/tcp   
registrator        Up 56 seconds
accent             Up 56 seconds     0.0.0.0:32792->80/tcp
```

Please, pay attention to the last row and especially to PORTS column. As you can see, this service publishes 32792 port. To check that my web service is achievable I go to `127.0.0.1:32972` on my host machine (the machine where I run docker compose up) and see this in browser:

```
Hello World
```

This is exactly what I wanted to see. However, it is not what I finally want. Please, have a look at the output of docker ps command and you will see, that my nginx service published 8181 port. So, my expectation is that when I go to this address - `127.0.0.1:8181` - I will see exactly the same "Hello world" page. However, it is not. In browser I see Bad Gateway error message and in nginx logs I see this error message

> nginx              | 2017/01/18 06:16:45 [error] 5#5: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:32792/index.php", host: "127.0.0.1:8181"

It is really interesting, because nginx does what I expect it to do - upstreams to "http://127.0.0.1:32792/index.php". But I'm not sure why does it fail. By the way, this is how nginx.conf (created automatically with Consul Template) looks like:

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream app_servers {
        server 127.0.0.1:32792;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        root /code;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri/ $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
         proxy_pass http://app_servers;
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
        }

    }
}
```

I wouldn't change anything, since this nginx.conf looks good to me. Trying to understand why it does not work, I shelled to nginx container and made a couple of commands:

```
$ curl accent
Hello World

$ curl 127.0.0.1:32972
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 32972: Connection refused

$ curl accent:32972
curl: (7) Failed to connect to accent port 32972: Connection refused
```

Again, it is interesting, because nginx container sees my web service under port `80` and not under its published `32972` port. Anyway, at this stage I do not know why it does not work and how to fix it. I just have a guess, that it is somehow connected to the way, how network is configured in docker-compose.yml. I tried various combinations of `network_mode: host` on accent and nginx service, but to no avail - either accent stops working or nginx or both. So, I need some help.

Comment: If it matters, MYHOST environment variable is set to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do port binding it publish some port from container (`80` in `accent` e.g.) and some port on your host (random `32792` on host e.g.).Containers in same network as your accent container can access your container port `80` by `accent` (same as `accent:80`) due to docker-compose services name resolving. You can access `accent:80` from your host with `accent:32792`. When you are requesting `127.0.0.1:32792` from your `nginx` container you can access only `nginx` container `32792` port, not `accent`. `accent:32792` is not correct url from anyway (`80` port open on `accent`, `32792` on host). But `127.0.0.1:32792` should work when you add `nginx` container to `host` network. But I noticed that you use incorrect port in `curl` call. Your `accent:80` published to host `32792` but you request `32972`.

Comment: Thanks! But does it all mean that I need to correct two things - set network_mode to host for nginx and in consul template for nginx.conf use accent:{{.Port}} instead of {{.Address}}:{{.Port}} ? In other words, I don't quite understand what exactly I need to do to fix it. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Or should I just change consul template and do it something like {{.Service}}:80? BTW I'm not quite sure what is the right key word for consul template, so that it would change the place holder with the actual service name (which is accent in my case).

Comment: it depends on how you want run your docker. If you just test consul and nginx in compose then you can add nginx to host network and set correct port in config. If you want to run your containers in prod with compose then you need publish only those ports which should be access externally. As I understood accent is not should be directly available from outside. Then it shouldn't publish their port to host. You can achieve very simple docker-compose load balancing using `scale` https://www.brianchristner.io/how-to-scale-a-docker-container-with-docker-compose/

Comment: When I slightly change my docker-compose.yml file and add just network_mode: host to nginx service, I then get an error message in nginx logs: `bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (Address already in use)`. I'm not sure what address it means and why it is in use. ((

Comment: It seems like I managed to create the correct configuration file for my proxy, using Consul Template. Now the only problem is how to restart nginx container from inside consul-template container.

Comment: For some reason, the last part of the command `-consul=${MYHOST}:8500 -wait=5s -template="/etc/ctmpl/nginx.ctmpl:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:docker kill -s HUP nginx"` does not work. I get an error message saying that "Can not connect to the Docker daemon". If I new how to overcome this problem, I would completely solve my task. Thanks!

Comment: I did it. Thanks to your advice!

Comment: How did you overcome the problem? I'm getting the same error with HaProxy.